# How to use auto scroll in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin

I have number of records and it have option like click and drag to change places like music player.

In this case, if 10 records is there it shows 4 in screen we have to scroll the screen to see another record.
For that , if I have to change my 10 record to first , click the 10th record and if I go up the page must be scroll to top.

any idea? for this auto scroll ..answer or suggestion comment please.

Comment: `ListView` has build in support for auto scrolling

Answer (score 0):

```
    //page view is may ui scroll view 
    //counter for if my image focus on last image then return on 1 img 
    //new PointF((float)(your image size * count),your top margin or your fram y);

    int count = 0;
                public async void StartTimer()
                {
                    await Task.Delay(3000); //3 sec 

                    count += 1;
                    if (count == 5)
                    {
                        count = 0;
                    }
                    var bottomOffset = new PointF((float)(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width * count),0);
                    pageview.SetContentOffset(bottomOffset, animated: true);
                    StartTimer();          


                }


public override void ViewDidLoad(){
 StartTimer();  
}
```